# Google Universal Analytics - Cross domain issue

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I have configured two properties under one account. First property has website name like `www.example.com` and my second property has website name like `www.abc.example.com`.

So in my case, if a user is active in the second website, it shows the same user as active in the first website also.

And my requirement is like if a user is active in the second website, it should not show the same user as active in the first website.

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a cross domain issue, it's a cross subdomain issue as you don't have two distinct domains. What is your GA code for each of the sites?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your cookieDomain and set it to auto.

[image]

By default Google Analytics will create the cookie for the first reached domain, in this case abc and example.com. Because of this, it is creating two different cookies for the two sub domains.

By setting it to auto, Google Analytics will create the cookie at the highest level prior to .com/.co.. etc. Therefore, through setting cookieDomain to auto, both abc.example.com and example.com will have client id's set up at the example.com level.

Edit:
There is also a good article written by Simo that addresses this in greater detail : https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/cross-domain-tracking-across-subdomains/